# How to retrieve the controls inside the selected item from a listbox in WP

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox, selecteditem

I'm now facing the most common problem faced my many while working with listboxes. Though I found many answers the the forum, nothing seems to work for me or else i have got it wrong. .

I have created a listbox through code. Every listbox item has a stackpanel and within it two textblocks. the stackpanel has vertical orientation.The foreground of the textblocks have been set to specific colors. When an item has been selected or clicked it moves to another page and on the close of the new page it returns to the old page.

My problem is that, when a listbox item has been clicked, it does not show the selection color which is by default the phones accent color before moving to the next page. Is it because the color of the textblocks have already set while creating the listbox?

So i tried to set it the foreground of the selected item through the SelectionChanged() like this

```
ListBoxItem selItem = (ListBoxItem)(listboxNotes.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(listboxNotes.SelectedIndex));
selItem .Foreground = (SolidColorBrush)Application.Current.Resources["PhoneAccentBrush"];
```

But this does not work, and i assume its cuz there is a stackpanel inside the item.

How exactly this needs to be done? Do i need to retrieve the textblocks inside the stackpanel and set the foreground?? I  have not used binding here. Visual Tree Helper???

Thanks

Alfah

Comment: I have never seen a selected/pressed color on a WP7 app. Are you sure you're designing to the platform?

Comment: @willmel yep. .the default listboxes have a pressed color. .

Comment: If you want a 'pressed' state, you should look at TiltEffect instead. http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Silverlight-for-WP7-Toolkit-TiltEffect-in-depth

Comment: @willmel Should i worry? :( I havn seen apps.. The foreground of selected item changes in both the listboxes i created. So i thought it was the default behaviour :(

Comment: @willmel yes i do have the tilt effect set for the page

Comment: You need to post your XAML for your ListBox's `DataTemplate`. And it **is** the default behaviour that a accent colour appear. But it's also considered poor UX.

Comment: Do I get your issue correctly? You want your selected item to have the same color when you navigate back that it had before you'd navigated away?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the selected color doesn't change on lists where you're navigating.

From my experience with android, there's no 'selector' background on WP7. If you're looking for a cool UI effect that shows some action is happening, the `TiltEffect` is definitely recommended, and very easy to implement.

http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Silverlight-for-WP7-Toolkit-TiltEffect-in-depth

However - if you're creating an app that doesn't have immediate navigation, it is possible that you might want a 'selected' cell color / etc. I've attached an image:

https://skydrive.live.com/redir.aspx?cid=ef08824b672fb5d8&resid=EF08824B672FB5D8!366&parid=EF08824B672FB5D8!343

If you note here, the buttons are related to the selected item on the list - I.e. the user can perform 4 different actions based on the selected item, (but they must select an item first!).

```
internal void SelectionChanged()
        {
    var item = (((ListBoxItem) _view.servers.SelectedItem).Content) as StackPanel;
                if (item != null)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < _view.servers.Items.Count; i++)
                    {
                        var val = (((ListBoxItem) _view.servers.Items[i]).Content) as StackPanel;
                        var tb = val.Children[0] as TextBlock;
                        var tb2 = val.Children[1] as TextBlock;
                        if (i == _view.servers.SelectedIndex)
                        {
                            tb.Foreground = tb2.Foreground = (SolidColorBrush) App.Current.Resources["PhoneAccentBrush"];
                        }
                        else


                       {
                                tb.Foreground = tb2.Foreground = (SolidColorBrush) //regular color here, b/c all these should no longer be selected
                            }

                        }
                    }
}
```

Comment: Actually there is a selector colour. Try with a standard ListBox.

Comment: @ClausJørgensen true - but it's not used in the same way that it is on Android.

Comment: @willmel its strange that i can see the textblock with foreground as the phones theme color when i click an item. :O

Comment: @willmel - I think you are confusing two effects. The selected item changed _foreground_ (text) colour once selected, not in its pressed state. The OP is referring to the former.

Comment: @willmel I kinda got it right through some convoluted method.. but now there is a selection :) I extracted the stackpanel from the selecteditem  as you have suggested then extracted the textboxes from it and set the color ;)

Answer (score 1):

The `ListItemContainer` will have it's `Foreground` changed automatically. To inherit this, simply don't specify a colour (or style) on your `TextBlock`.

Comment: yea. .I realised that. .But the items in the list box are set to specific colors according to some data. I need the colors set. Is there any way that i can then specify a selected color?